# Flush equations left with breqn

Tags: equations, article, breqn

I am using the `breqn` package to automatically break equations, like this:

```
  \begin{dmath}
   a = b + c + d + e + f + g + h +i + j + k + l + m + n + p + q
  \end{dmath}
```

I would like to have all my equations flushed to the left. However, the option `fleqn` used as follows:

```
 \documentclass[fleqn]{article}
```

does not seem to achieve this (flushing equations to the left) for the `breqn` provided environments like `dmath` (though it works with `equation`).  Is there any way to automatically flush all equations to the left while using `breqn` environments?

MWEs:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, breqn}
\begin{document}
\noindent Test is there.
\begin{equation*}
   a = b + c + d + e + f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+      f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f 
\end{equation*}
\noindent Test is here.
\end{document}
```

The above flushes the equation to the left, but the following does not flush left.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, breqn}
\begin{document}
\noindent Test is there.
\begin{dmath*}
   a = b + c + d + e + f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+      f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f+ f 
\end{dmath*}
\noindent Test is here.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `mathindent` to be zero.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{breqn,showframe}             %% showframe only for showing frames.
\begin{document}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
  \begin{dmath}    
   a = b + c + d + e + f + g + h +i + j + k + l + m + n + p + q
  \end{dmath}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the sake of completeness (the OP did not asked for that), the change can be made local via `\begin{dmath}[style={\mathindent=0pt}]...\end{dmath}`.